# Objective: To be able to use contexthub on an AEM 6.2 site

Tags: aem, sightly

We have a sample site which has a basic template and a page level component.
In its `head.html` we have included the context hub which is not reflecting on the page. The code snippet for `head.html` of our sample site as shown below:

```
<head>
  <sly data-sly-resource="${ @ path = 'contexthub' , resourceType='libs/granite/contexthub/components/contexthub'}"></sly>
  <title>${head.title}</title>
</head>
```

As per my understanding, To enable the **ContextHub** features we need to include ***contexthub*** component in the head section of our page level component. I am still unable to see the contexthub component on my page. Please correct if am missing any step in implementing the same.

Comment: did you followed the [adobe contexthub](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/personalization/contexthub/ch-adding.html) documentation. can you provide what else you have done triage?

Comment: Yes , I did but it is not appearing on the page.Kindly refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228225/to-use-contexthub-on-an-aem-site for the code snippet that i have used

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head>
  <meta data-sly-resource="${'./config' @resourceType='cq/personalization/components/clientcontext_optimized/config'}" data-sly-unwrap></meta>
  <meta data-sly-resource="${'./contexthub' @resourceType='granite/contexthub/components/contexthub'}" data-sly-unwrap></meta>
  <title>${head.title}</title>
</head>
```